# ARCore augmented image - The Object you want to instantiate is null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to create a app that will recognise images and add different objects to them. I'm working off the Google augmentedimage example.

I have two objects sphere and a cube. Both are prefabs and both have AugmentedImageVisualizer assigned to them.

AugmentedImageExampleController separates images as it should but when AugmentedImageVisualizer wants to enable visibility for cube or sphere it fails with error The object you want to instantiate is null.

Here are scripts

```
public class AugmentedImageExampleController : MonoBehaviour
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// A prefab for visualizing an AugmentedImage.
     /// </summary>
     public AugmentedImageVisualizer[] AugmentedImageVisualizerPrefab;

     /// <summary>
     /// The overlay containing the fit to scan user guide.
     /// </summary>
     public GameObject FitToScanOverlay;

     private Dictionary<int, AugmentedImageVisualizer> m_Visualizers
         = new Dictionary<int, AugmentedImageVisualizer>();

     private List<AugmentedImage> m_TempAugmentedImages = new List<AugmentedImage>();

     /// <summary>
     /// The Unity Update method.
     /// </summary>
     public void Update()
     {
         // Exit the app when the 'back' button is pressed.
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
         {
             Application.Quit();
         }

         // Get updated augmented images for this frame.
         Session.GetTrackables<AugmentedImage>(
             m_TempAugmentedImages, TrackableQueryFilter.Updated);



         // Create visualizers and anchors for updated augmented images that are tracking and do
         // not previously have a visualizer. Remove visualizers for stopped images.
         foreach (var image in m_TempAugmentedImages)
         {
             int i = image.DatabaseIndex;
             AugmentedImageVisualizer visualizer = null;
             m_Visualizers.TryGetValue(image.DatabaseIndex, out visualizer);

             Debug.Log(image.DatabaseIndex);
             if (image.TrackingMethod  == AugmentedImageTrackingMethod.FullTracking && visualizer == null)
             {
                 // Create an anchor to ensure that ARCore keeps tracking this augmented image.
                 Anchor anchor = image.CreateAnchor(image.CenterPose);
                 Debug.Log("Anchor created");

                 visualizer = (AugmentedImageVisualizer)Instantiate(
                     AugmentedImageVisualizerPrefab[i], anchor.transform);
                 visualizer.Image = image;
                 m_Visualizers.Add(image.DatabaseIndex, visualizer);
             }
             else if (image.TrackingMethod  == AugmentedImageTrackingMethod.NotTracking && visualizer != null)
             {
                 m_Visualizers.Remove(image.DatabaseIndex);
                 GameObject.Destroy(visualizer.gameObject);


             }
          
         }

         // Show the fit-to-scan overlay if there are no images that are Tracking.
         foreach (var visualizer in m_Visualizers.Values)
         {
             if (visualizer.Image.TrackingMethod  == AugmentedImageTrackingMethod.FullTracking)
             {
                 FitToScanOverlay.SetActive(false);
                 return;
             }
         }

         FitToScanOverlay.SetActive(true);
     }
 }
```

and Visualiser script

```
public class AugmentedImageVisualizer : MonoBehaviour
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// The AugmentedImage to visualize.
     /// </summary>
       public AugmentedImage Image;

  

     public GameObject prefabToInstantiate;

     /// <summary>
     /// The Unity Update method.
     /// </summary>
     public void Update()
     {
         if (Image == null || Image.TrackingMethod != AugmentedImageTrackingMethod.FullTracking)
         {
          
             prefabToInstantiate.SetActive(false);

             return;
         }

         float halfWidth = Image.ExtentX / 2;
         float halfHeight = Image.ExtentZ / 2;
         prefabToInstantiate.transform.localPosition =
             (halfWidth * Vector3.left) + (halfHeight * Vector3.back);
         prefabToInstantiate.SetActive(true);

     }

 }
```

I tried to solve the problem with instantiating it at start with Instantiate()

In visualizer but it still failed. Original example doesn't use it it just enables gameobject's visibility.

Screenshots:
Example controller:
[image]

Sphere and cube are the same:
[image]

```
Unity error: 07-13 14:02:39.642 32121 32161 E Unity   : ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.
07-13 14:02:39.642 32121 32161 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object original, UnityEngine.Transform parent, System.Boolean instantiateInWorldSpace) [0x00044] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs:261 
07-13 14:02:39.642 32121 32161 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original, UnityEngine.Transform parent, System.Boolean worldPositionStays) [0x00001] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs:291 
07-13 14:02:39.642 32121 32161 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original, UnityEngine.Transform parent) [0x00001] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs:286 
07-13 14:02:39.642 32121 32161 E Unity   :   at GoogleARCore.Examples.AugmentedImage.AugmentedImageExampleController.Update () [0x0009f] in C:\Users\\arcore\Assets\GoogleARCore\Examples\AugmentedImage\Scripts\AugmentedImageExampleController.cs:90
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace please?

Comment: Do you mean error message? Since I don't  have a laptop or a webcam I can only live-test on my phone and I get back  ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.

Comment: Yes the error from the Unity console.

Comment: ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null. That's everything sadly

Comment: This thread can help you how to debug and view the logs on an Android device [How To - Capturing Device Logs on Android](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-capturing-device-logs-on-android.528680/)

Comment: I posted detailed error in the post

Comment: Are you using the last version of the examples scripts from [arcore-unity-sdk examples](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/tree/master/Assets/GoogleARCore/Examples/AugmentedImage/Scripts)?

Comment: `AugmentedImageExampleController.cs:90` what is this line please?

Comment: @loic.lopez visualizer = (AugmentedImageVisualizer)Instantiate(
                        AugmentedImageVisualizerPrefab[i], anchor.transform); and yes I installed the latest version of it from official website of arcore

Comment: So you are passing to `Instantiate` a null reference it can be in ` AugmentedImageVisualizerPrefab[i]`

Comment: What could cause the problem ... becouse I pass script correctly

Comment: does the unmodified scripts from the example are working?

Comment: Yes but I need each image to display a different object

Comment: You can try to create multiple object in the scene which have `AugmentedImageExampleController` and `AugmentedImageVisualizer` for each object in a scene

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.